# Windows 8 hibernation does not work

Tags: windows-8, hibernate

I installed Win8 on my new ThinkPad x230t. I enabled Hibernation. When activate hibernation, the system shuts down. But on the next start, the system starts as normal and all opened applications (and unsaved work) is lost. hiberfil.dat exists. What could be the issue?

The partition with Windows (C) is encrypted with DiskCryptor. The harddrive is an SSD.

Comment: Its entirely possible the problem is because of DiskCryptor i woudl contact the author to confirm.

Comment: Yes, seems so. I ended up using TrueCrypt and it works. I contacted the author (ntldr) multiple times but no response. Very sad ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DiskCryptor does not work yet with Windows 8. It's a bug. It works well with Windows 7.

Unfortunately the author does not answer emails at all.